# Unknown type name Xcode shenanigans

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, avfoundation, avplayer

Xcode is once again trying to drive me nuts.

Today, out of the blue, Xcode stopped building my OS X project. It fails to recognise `AVPlayer` of `AVFoundation`, even when `AVFoundation` is imported right there.

[image]

I tried cleaning, deleting `DerivedData` and restarting the computer. What might be the problem here?

### Update

The problem solved itself after semi-random combination of cleaning, deleting DerivedData, re-linking the framework and restarting Xcode, which makes me think the problem was caused by a hard to reproduce Xcode bug. This question might be too localised to be useful to others. Please vote to close it you agree. And thanks to everyone who chimed in.

Comment: SO needs more use of the word 'shenanigans' :D

Comment: Did you try to unlink, clean and re-link AVFoundation Library?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 Yes, that too. Actually, I didn't clean in-between.

Comment: Did you add the framework to your project?

Comment: Maybe you are mistaken about what unlinking and relinking a framework means? Adding #import... doesn't mean anything if you don't actually add the framework to your project.  
  
From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html :  
  
_To include a framework in your Xcode project, choose Project > Add to Project and select the framework directory. Alternatively, you can control-click your project group and choose Add Files > Existing Frameworks from the contextual menu._

Comment: @harrisg The framework is added to the project.

Comment: The problem solved itself after semi-random combination of cleaning, deleting DerivedData, re-linking the framework and restarting Xcode. This question might be too localised to be useful to others. Will delete it tomorrow if there's no further discussion. Thanks to everyone who chimed in.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to sound extremely bizarre but after some messing around, I was able to duplicate a bizarre behavior, that I am hoping is related, by removing the #import "RMVideoView.h" from the m file. It seems there is something going on with the sequence of events.

1- I opened a new Mac project and created an NSView subclass and put your code in the .h file. I run it with no errors.

2- Did a clean

3- Now, delete your

`#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> from the .h file`

4- Do  a clean. Now, If I remove the #import"RMVideoView.h" from the .m file, oddly you can't get the automatic completion anymore when putting

`#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` in the .h file! These 2 should not be related

5- Try it again. Put back your #import"RMVideoView.h" in the .m file. Do a clean and now autocomplete works when inserting  `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` in the .h file. This kind of got me to try the next step

6- Move your #import `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` to the .m file and oddly enough you do not get any errors in the .h file.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It didn't, but thanks for trying. +1